# App crashes while loading image but not always

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

```
    Type
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed (RequestManagerRetriever.java:317)
  at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get (RequestManagerRetriever.java:128)
  at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with (Glide.java:801)
  at MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$4$MainActivity (MainActivity.java:237)
  at MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda9.onComplete (Unknown Source:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8663)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Tested on many devices but still can get this crash. Application is doing fine but by Google Crash Details, this crash appears on different devices and different SDKs. Not so many times but it appears.

Here's my code:

```
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String s = task.getResult().getString("image");
    
                            if(s == null || s.equals("")){
                                //theres no image, put default url (imageURL)
                                s = imageURL;
                                iv_login.setImageResource( R.drawable.b);
                            }
                            else{
                                RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();   
                                Glide.with(MainActivity.this)                            
.setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.b))
                                            .load(s)
                                            .into(iv_login);
                           }
```

Comment: So it's more a Glide-related question, rather than a Firebase one, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try once

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
String s = task.getResult().getString("image");
if(s == null || s.equals("")){
//theres no image, put default url (imageURL)
s = imageURL;                              
Glide
.with(MainActivity.this)
.load(s)
.placeholder(R.drawable.b)
.into(iv_login);
}
else{
Glide
.with(MainActivity.this)
.load(s)
.placeholder(R.drawable.b)
.into(iv_login);
}
```

or use this with your requirement.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(url).into(holder.imageView);
```